# How to flatten 3D matrices into arrays?

Tags: c++, matrix, linear-algebra

I'm trying to flatten 3D matrices of arbitrary sizes into arrays such that values can be retrieved from arrays based on the spatial indexes `i`, `j`, and `k`. Clearly, each array index will have to be unique. I've tried setting the array index to `int idx = i + width * (j + height * k)`, but that's not unique because `(1,0,0)` and `(0,1,0)` would give the same index if `width == 1`. Does anyone know of a better way to index or flatten 3D matrices?

Comment: Your expression for a flattened index is correct. If `width == 1`, `1` is out of bounds.

Comment: @Evg Oh, OOB. Of course. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula is OK, because if `width == 1`, then `j` must be always `0`